# RoboGuice, RoboBlender and Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, roboguice

I use RoboGuice 3.0 alpha-2, have been doing so for quite a while, and I'm happy with it. Now I wanted to upgrade to RoboGuice-3.0 or -3.01, but that I can't get to work.

I use Eclipse (I use Android Studio in some project but I really don't like it), RoboBlender complains about AnnotationDatabaseImpl not being there. When I disable Roboblender, I get

```
E/AndroidRuntime(18825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18825): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.inject.internal.util.$Maps
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at com.google.inject.assistedinject.BindingCollector.<init>(BindingCollector.java:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder.<init>(FactoryModuleBuilder.java:206)
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at com.loqli.android.robo.GossipModule.configure(GossipModule.java:260)
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:78)
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:252)
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at roboguice.RoboGuice.createGuiceInjector(RoboGuice.java:186)
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at roboguice.RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:151)
E/AndroidRuntime(18825):    at roboguice.RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:90)
```

I moved back to alpha-2, but now I wonder, should RG and RB work with Eclipse and ant?

Edit: I mentioned "Eclipse". I'm not interested in how it works on Android Studio, I want to know how to make it work in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way in eclipse would be to [set RoboBlender up as annotation processor](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_apt_getting_started.htm). It didn't get this to work, though (see bellow).

## Maven - working solution

Here's how I got it working - using Maven. Maven generates the Annotation Database to `target\generated-sources\annotations`. So I simply added this path as source folder in eclipse and voilà no more `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AnnotationDatabaseImpl`!

## Ant - similar solution?

From your question I presume you're using ant?! Maybe you can [set up the annotation processing with ant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644624/1845976) instead of maven?

## Eclipse annotation processor - a further approach

As mentioned, I first tried to use eclipse annotation processor and almost got it working.
I added [RoboBlender and its transitive dependencies](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/roboguice/roboblender/3.0.1/roboblender-3.0.1.pom) to the Factory Path. For RoboBlender 3.0.1, this is

1. [RoboBlender](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/roboguice/roboblender/3.0.1/roboblender-3.0.1.jar), its dependency
2. [velocity](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/velocity-1.7.jar) and its dependencies
3. [commons-collections](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar) and
4. [commons-lang](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar).

Because I use multiple modules with annotation databases, I add the Processor Option `guiceAnnotationDatabasePackageName`.

This resulted in an info message in my eclipse error log that said `Impossible to generate annotation database.`, which is exactly the message of the [generic exception thrown by the RoboGuice's AnnotationDatabaseGenerator](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/bf9043c5af085408a5d26ea8e5f857e8d0a9bdab/guice/blender/src/com/google/inject/blender/AnnotationDatabaseGenerator.java#L51).
[image: EclipseErrorLog]
Unfortunately, there are no stacktraces or anything, so I gave up here and found the solution using maven as stated above. Maybe someone else can find the missing piece here?
If it helps you can find the project where I use RoboBlender [here](https://github.com/schnatterer/nusic).

Answer (score 0):

The AnnotationDatabaseImpl class is generated by RoboBlender at compile time.

You can specify the following as a Java Compiler Argument ( use your package name )

```
-AguiceAnnotationDatabasePackageName=some.package.name.here
```

This should generate the class you need at compile time.

Then in your manifest you need to point to the same package

```
 <meta-data android:name="roboguice.annotations.packages" android:value="some.package.name.here"/>
```

For a maven setup reference the answer here:

[Injected objects became null after upgrading to Roboguice 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367525/injected-objects-became-null-after-upgrading-to-roboguice-3/27406668#27406668)

Comment: Ah. I did the thing in the manifest, but not the property. I'll try.

Comment: But I guess I'll have to switch to Android Studio sooner or later, unfortunately...

Comment: I added the java compiler argument, I already had the meta-data line in my manifest, but it still won't generate the AnnotationDatabaseImpl file.

Comment: I did this in Intellij and did a complete rebuild. You should be able to see the class crop up under the generated-sources and in the target classes directory. Without the meta tag it generates a class in the root of the classes directory ( no package name ).

Comment: I have switched to Android Studio now (unfortunately), so this issue isn't that important for me any more.